# Maps app crashing

Tags: google-maps, force-close

I have a Google play edition of the S4. Lately, I keep getting the window telling me that unfortunately maps has stopped working. The problem is I'm not actively using the app, but it does run through Google Now. I cleared its cache, data and even forced stopped it to see if anything would change but nothing. Help?

Comment: Can you disable it (*Settings→Apps*, Maps: is there a "disable" button)? If so, does that help?

Comment: Ill give it a shot. I'm sure it does but I use google now a lot just to view traffic/driving times and wouldnt want to lose that

Comment: Um, that contradicts the *I'm not even using the app*. But in that case, if disabling does the trick, [Greenify](http://www.appbrain.com/app/greenify/com.oasisfeng.greenify) might be worth a second shot. Might need either root, the [donation package](http://www.appbrain.com/app/greenify-%28donation-package%29/com.oasisfeng.greenify.pro), or both, though.

Comment: I have a mac and Ive tried to root my phone but it never works. The free Greenify wont even locate the map app

Answer (score 1):

Just go to Settings - Apps - Maps and uninstall updates. It may be that the new updates are the reason it crashes.

It would be good if you can switch off location setting in Google Now because every time you use Google now it starts locating via network or gps and starts up the map application in the background.